# Ruby: Split string with occurence

Tags: regex, ruby, string, split

I have a string like :

```
"Premier League>Arsenal|Bayern Munich|Breaking News|Premier League>Chelsea|Ligue 1>Lille|Premier League>Liverpool|Premier League>Manchester-City|Premier League>Manchester-United|MercaShow|Mercato|Ligue 1>PSG"
```

i would like to split > charactere.
i would like the result to look like

```
["Premier League", "Arsenal|Bayern Munich|Breaking News", "Premier League", "Chelsea", "Ligue 1", etc ...]
```

But i can't figure out how to acheive this.
If i do `my_string.split(">")` i only get:

```
["Premier League", "Arsenal|Bayern Munich|Breaking News|Premier League", "Chelsea|Ligue 1", etc...]
```

I would like to buid categories and sub categories parsing this string.
ex:

```
Premier League>Arsenal|Bayern Munich|Breaking News|Premier League>Chelsea|Ligue 1>Lille|
```

should give :

- Premier League

  - Arsenal
  - Bayern Munich
  - Breaking News
- Premier League

  - Chelsea
- Ligue 1

  - Lille

Comment: You seam to want to split your string by `>` AND `|` no ?

Comment: Why would `"Breaking News|Premier League"` get split?

Comment: @Fravadona yes i would like to split by > and |

Comment: @tadman i would like to build a kind of tree.

Premier League (">" parent)
    "Arsenal|Bayern Munich|Breaking News| ("|" Children)

Comment: i mean, every words followed by > should be parent (categories).
And every word separated by | should be children (subcategories)

I am trying to build model association with those strings

Comment: Use `str.split /[>|]/` and then parse your array into a nested hash. It's not trivial, but should be doable as a multi-pass operation.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `|` in front of `>` with another character (eg.`<`) and then split it.

```
s="Premier League>Arsenal|Bayern Munich|Breaking News|Premier League>Chelsea|Ligue 1>Lille|Premier League>Liverpool|Premier League>Manchester-City|Premier League>Manchester-United|MercaShow|Mercato|Ligue 1>PSG"

p s.gsub(/\|([^\|]+)>/,"<\\1>").split("<").
    map{|x| a=x.split(">"); [a[0], a[1].split("|")]}
```

Alternatively, parse the string from the back.

```
a=[]
s="Premier League>Arsenal|Bayern Munich|Breaking News|Premier League>Chelsea|Ligue 1>Lille|Premier League>Liverpool|Premier League>Manchester-City|Premier League>Manchester-United|MercaShow|Mercato|Ligue 1>PSG"
while /\b([^\|]+)>([^>]+)$/ === s do
    s=$`
    a.unshift([$1, $2.split('|')])
end
p a
```

I don't think it is easy to split the string directlty.